# SQL query using CTE not working after database migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cte

We have recently migrated an application, and in the process we have migrated from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have noticed that some SQL queries using CTE do not work anymore since.

I have tried simplifying the queries, but to no avail.
Even this following simple query (which gets the top parent in a hierarchy) ends up with the error message hereunder :

Code:

```
DECLARE @Companies TABLE (
      AccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
      ,NAME VARCHAR(100)
      ,ParentAccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
      )

INSERT INTO @Companies
SELECT 
      AccountId
      ,NAME
      ,ParentAccountId
FROM AccountBase;

WITH CTE
AS (
      SELECT *
            ,0 [Level]
      FROM @Companies

      UNION ALL

      SELECT 
            CTE.accountid
            ,CTE.NAME
            ,cmp.ParentAccountId
            ,LEVEL + 1
      FROM CTE
            INNER JOIN @Companies AS cmp ON CTE.ParentAccountId = cmp.AccountId
      WHERE 
            cmp.ParentAccountId IS NOT NULL
      )
SELECT 
      c.AccountId
      ,c.NAME
      ,c.ParentAccountId as TopParentAccountId
FROM (
      SELECT *
            ,MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) [MaxLevel]
      FROM CTE
      ) c
WHERE 
      MaxLevel = LEVEL
```

Error message (msg 530):

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion.

What could be possible reasons ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something changed in your data? You can increase the limit with MAXRECURSION option

Comment: The concerned table has not be changed.. much ! I.e. some obsolete fields were removed, but it is all. i have indeed tried to change the MAXRECURSION, up to the limit and it did not work either.

Comment: You need to increase the `maxrecursion` (default is 100) or set no limit with `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: Can you check if this returns any rows? `SELECT * FROM AccountBase WHERE ParentAccountId = AccountId ;`

Comment: @ypercube No, it does not return anything (and it should not).

Comment: I did not know about infinite recursion with MAXRECURSION 0 (thanks indeed @ypercube by the way). However it does not solve my problem; on the former database, the query executes in 20 seconds. In the current database, I have set infinite recursion, but still have no results after 15 minutes (and counting).

Comment: Perhaps something is blocking the query? And are you talking about the specific query or some other? It's not uncommon to have a miswritten recursive CTE that falls into an infinite loop. For the specific query, a (finite) loop on the parent-ids, say `(id, parentid) = values (1,2), (2,3), (3,1)` will cause an infinite recursion loop, I think.

Comment: I am still talking about the query from my question :) The current database has, obviously, more recent data, so there could very well be bad data that could lead to an infinite recursive loop, whereas the query ran without problem in the former database. I will look into the data (and probably also try to find a way to break the loop if such cases should arise).

Comment: There were indeed two cases where two entities were each the parent of the other. Yay ! :D. I have notified the concerned users so that they can correct the data, and I will put constraints so that it does not happen again.. Thanks @ypercube for pointing me the way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

The obvious reason for this error is that the query needed to do recursion of more than 100 levels. So you can try increasing the default of 100 to higher (say 1000) or to no limit with `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

Another possibility is to have "bad data" (i.e. cycles in the `id - parent_id` adjacency list relationship) and not well written recursive CTE that falls into an infinite loop.

For the specific query, a cycle on the id - parent ids, say `(AccountId, ParentAccountId)` with  values `(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)` will cause an infinite recursion loop.

I suggest you check the data in the table for cycles in the `id - parent_id` relationship and correct the query to avoid infinite recursion in any case this happens again.

Comment: In my case, as we discussed in the question comments, it was indeed bad data. Thanks again :)